How to read seven segment display and logos in images using Python?
I have a bunch of photos of energy meters. In every photo there is info written on the meter and also a seven segment display which has reading in kWh. Also, there is logo of meter manufacturer. I want to extract information like meter serial number, meter manufacturer, meter reading in kWh(7 segmented display).
I have used easyocr module to detect text and using that I have achieved to extract meter serial numbers but for kWh reading easyocr fails to detect the digital digits.
Currently I have 2 requirements, one is to detect digits from 7 segment display and also detect manufacturer from logo symbol in meter. Only 2-3 different manufacturers are there so I need to train based on only 2-3 logos. But I don't know how to do it.
Any help or guidance with steps kr procedure will be really appreciated.
I tried googling, searched on YouTube but not getting any roadmap for the same. I have tried other ocr modules like tesseract but it also fails.

Try using this repository.
https://github.com/renjithsasidharan/seven-segment-ocr
It seems to work according to the results they have provided. Since this is implemented in Tensorflow lite, I think it would be ideal for faster inference.
If you have time to look into this paper as well

Thank you so much for giving your time. I will surely try it. Also, can you suggest how to make my script recognise logos of meter. Can you suggest some libraries or any procedure?

If I get this problem, I will experiment with some pre-trained deep-learning CNN models such as VGG or resnet and fine-tune the models for your task. In this case recognising logos by classifying them. You can use PyTorch or Tensorflow depending on your preference and experience. Here's some tutorial in Tensorflow for fine-tuning pretrained models for your dataset. If you don't have a dataset, you might have to create a dataset for the logos of meter.

This is a tutorial in pytorch  for classifying flowers. Similar to your porblem.
